# Mocha: How Can I Structure Things to Run Setup Code *Before* App Code Loads?

Tags: javascript, mocha.js

**TLDR:** Is there any way to run Mocha test setup code before the application code *loads* (not just before the test code runs), without having to import that setup code in every test file?

**Background:**

I have a client-side application I'm trying to test with Mocha.  One of my modules in that app does something to the effect of:

```
// foo.js
const initialReduxState = { currentLocation: window.location };
```

The problem is, `window` doesn't exist in the test environment, so I have to mock one for my tests:

```
// testSetup.js
before(() => {
    const { window } = new JSDOM(`...`);
    global.window = window;
});
```

But if I actually use `before` like I just did, it won't work, because the testSetup code will load, then the application code (which needs `window`) will load, then the `before` in the test setup will run (too late).

So instead I wound up adding it directly inside a "master test loader" file, without a before:

```
// masterTestLoader.js
const { window } = new JSDOM(`...`);
beforeEach(() => {
    global.window = window;
});
import 'fooTest';
```

But if I do that I can only run the whole suite; I can't run individual test files.  So instead I went back to having a `testSetup.js` file, removed the `before`, and started importing `testSetup.js` in my tests:

```
// fooTest.js
import 'testSetup'; run this first to create window
import 'foo'; // uses window
testSomething();
```

but the downside of that is that I have to explicitly include the `testSetup.js` in every single test file.

I also tried using the mocha `--require` command line option to require `testSetup` (without having to require it in each test file) ... but it turns out files that get loaded that way don't get the Mocha globals (like `beforeEach`).

My question is, is there any way to get the best of both worlds?  In other words,  is there any way to ensure that some code for a Mocha test runs not just before the test code, but before the application code ... without having to import that code explicitly in every test file?

Comment: You could create the window object once before loading all the other stuff, but that means each test uses that same window object. Maybe you can create it once before loading all other stuff, and then recreate it the `after` of each test.

Comment: Yeah, that's definitely my goal.  Where I'm fuzzy is the "in practice, how do I actually do that before my application code loads (without having to require the setup at the top of every test file)?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can invoke mocha like this:

```
mocha --require testSetup.js
```

where `testSetup.js` contains everything that you want to be run before the actual test loads.

Alternatively, you can create a `mocha.opts` file next to your `package.json` that contains the `--require testSetup.js`, which will be loaded automatically on each test run.

Comment: Thanks, but the problem with that approach is that `--require` doesn't load the Mocha globals, so I can't use `beforeEach` (to refresh the mock DOM before each test) inside `testSetup.js`  if I do that.

Comment: BTW, I also found the `--file` option, which seemed promising, but evidently it doesn't work with the `--recursive` option (which I'm also using).

Comment: Actually it looks like updating my Mocha version fixed it.